# Using machine learning to evaluate a random number generator

Tags: generative-models

Let's say that I want to create a pseudorandom number generator, and I'd like to make sure that it's truly close to random. For simplicity, let's assume that I want to output a 0 or a 1 randomly.

I have heard of the monobit, runs, poker test etc. but are there "machine learning" ways to evaluate a pseudorandom number generator?

As in, one could try to predict the number that will be outputted given the first k numbers that were previously outputted, and the performance of that model would give you how well the pseudorandom generator is performing.

It might be way over my head, but could a generative adversarial network learn a truly pseudorandom generator that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are there "machine learning" ways to evaluate a pseudorandom number generator?

No it is the wrong tool for the job. Statistical tests, like those you mention *monobit, runs, poker test* etc, are a way to evaluate a PRNG and search for bias or unwanted patterns which would establish that it had flaws.

If you try to use ML on random data - e.g. map dependent x,y data to a label z where all are determined randomly - then one sign the data is random will be that the ML does poorly. However, this will not give any measure of quality of the randomness. Using a high variance model it will still be possible to fit the data, although cross validation and test sets will score badly.

> It might be way over my head, but could a generative adversarial network learn a truly pseudorandom generator that way?

A GAN learns how to map a low dimensional space into a manifold (sub-shape) of a larger dimensional space, allowing you to sample from a population in the higher dimension. It cannot inject "noise" into that space other than using something provided already by a PRNG. The GAN itself cannot be the PRNG. The GAN sampling routine is typically driven by an external PRNG (i.e. not driven by the weights or processing of the GAN)

Probably you could construct a PRNG from a RNN, although I suspect it would be hard to create one of any quality, and even if you could get something close to statistical randomness from it, the performance is likely to be poor compared to standards such as Mersenne Twister.